# VueJS array manipulation from children

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm dealing with a problem I can't figure out where I have an array of items that should be rendered in a component but inside that component they can be manipulated into a new array, so whenever a change is made into one of the items it should be pushed into the `itemsToEdit` array, instead of modifying the original item because later I need to send that new array to the server with only items modified and only the fields modified...

My child component has a simple checkbox (that is working the way it should) with a `checked` property which shows the default value if given, and a `v-model` with all the logic that actually works.

If I set up the `v-model` to `v-model="item.show"` it changes the original item, so there's nothing to change in there, but I can't send from parent to children the `itemsToEdit` array because it is empty and `v-model="items.id.show"` won't work.

I've worked with multiple checkboxes and an array `v-model` but it is a different workflow because I actually edit the original array of items, so it will push/remove items as I check the checkboxes but that's not what I want, the original array should stay as it is all the time.

Here's my simplified code, the children actually has a lot of checkboxes but I'll show just one because simplicity.

Parent component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <TestComponent v-for="i in items" :key="i.id" :item="i" :items-to-edit="itemsToEdit"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from '@/TestComponent'
export default {
    name: 'MyParent',
    components: { TestComponent },
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                { id: 1, name: 'test', show: false },
                { id: 2, name: 'test 2', show: false },
                { id: 3, name: 'test 3', show: true },
                { id: 4, name: 'test 4', show: false }
            ],
            itemsToEdit: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <MyCheckbox :checked="item.show"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TestComponent',
    components: { MyCheckbox },
    props: ['item', 'itemsToEdit']
}
</script>
```

EDIT: One thing I forgot, I obviously can use `$emit` and listen on parent then push into the array, but that's not what I want, I am looking for a better way to implement this, if I have no other option, I will go with the events.

EDIT2: I can't 'clone' original array into the `itemsToEdit` because I want that array to be only filled up whenever a real change comes in, because later, the request send to server will only contain real changes, if I send the whole array of id's it will try to modify them even if they have no changes so it will be a waste of performance checking everything serverside.

Comment: You can just add another array to your data, say, `currentItems`, and make its initial value a copy of the original array. Then, on your code, mutate `currentItems` instead of `items`

Comment: I've updated my question because I forgot to mention that I don't want to do what you say, because that'll be like using the original array which is not what I want, I wonly want the real changes to be pushed, if some item hasn't changed, it shouldn't be on the edit array ^^

Comment: You didn't get it, I meant using three arrays (items, currentItems, and itemsToEdit) instead of the two you currently use

Comment: No judgement, but why are you trying to work around using the event/`$emit` approach?

Comment: @BDawg because I'm looking towards another way to handle it, I know I can do it with events but if I can do it in a way I don't even need to listen for stuff, that's better, because we don't have buttons (I wish... that'll simplify all), everything should be fired through checks, hence the `v-model` approach (which of course may or not may be the best solution) I'm just curious about how other people would approach this without `$emit`s.
@Ayrton oh yeah, didn't get it at all, but it will have the same effect as using the original one, right? I'll have items without changes inside that array?

Comment: If you initialise your currentItems with a copy of the original items and then mutate only the current ones, I see no reason why your items array would change. Give it a try

Comment: If you were to be presented code using `$emit` that didn't rely on buttons, would you find that acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your selected approach, my recommendation is to **keep your list logic in one place** (if you can) for the sake of easier maintenance. [Side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) are necessary at times, but they can be very difficult to work with as they spread out.

Also, I'm not sure if this is the problem you are running into, but I can see why `$emit` might be a problem if you made a different event for each of your checkboxes/changed values. I think you can consolidate this into a single event like `item-updated` to prevent things from getting too unwieldy. For example, in the snippet below, I've used a shared method named `updateItem` in the input event listeners on each checkbox like this: `@change="updateItem({ show: $event.target.checked })"` and `@change="updateItem({ active: $event.target.checked })"`. This way, there is just one `$emit` call (inside the updateItem method). Try running the snippet below - I think it should give you the results you were looking for:

```js
Vue.config.devtools=false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Parent element
Vue.component('v-items', {
  template: `
    <div class="items">
      <div class="items__list">
        <v-item v-for="i in items" :key="i.id" :item="i" @item-updated="itemUpdated"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data () {
    const origItems = [
      { id: 1, name: 'test', show: false, active: true },
      { id: 2, name: 'test 2', show: false, active: true },
      { id: 3, name: 'test 3', show: true, active: true },
      { id: 4, name: 'test 4', show: false, active: true },
    ]
    return {
      origItems,
      items: origItems.map(item => Object.assign({}, item)),
      editedItems: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    itemUpdated(item) {
      const origItem = this.origItems.find(o => o.id === item.id)
      const indexInEdited = this.editedItems.findIndex(o => o.id === item.id)
      const objectChanged = JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(origItem)
      
      if (indexInEdited !== -1) {
        this.editedItems.splice(indexInEdited, 1)
      }

      if (objectChanged) {
        this.editedItems.push(item)
      }
      
      // Show the editedItems list
      console.clear()
      console.log(this.editedItems)
    }
  },
})

// Child elements
Vue.component('v-item', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `
    <div class="item">
      <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
      <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
      <input type="checkbox"
        :checked="item.show"
        @change="updateItem({ show: $event.target.checked })"
      />
      <input type="checkbox"
        :checked="item.active"
        @change="updateItem({ active: $event.target.checked })"
      />
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    updateItem(update) {
      // Avoid directly modifying this.item by creating a cloned object
      this.$emit('item-updated', Object.assign({}, this.item, update))
    }
  },
})

new Vue({ el: "#app" })

console.clear()
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

.items__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto auto;
  gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-items></v-items>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! You got the point about the checkboxes :D Thanks for your code, it helped me to see thinks from another perspective and ended up with something working ^^

Comment: Glad it helped!